# How can I mark two responses as answers?

Tags: support, voting

It seems that every time I mark one as answer it toggles off the other.

Comment: Question thanks to Christophe Humbert: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/users/995/christophe

Answer (score 5):

People familiar with MSDN and TechNet forums would be used to seeing multiple posts marked as answers in their questions.
[SharePoint Overflow](http://www.sharepointoverflow.com) (like other sites spawned from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)) doesn't take this approach.

The system is instead optimised for users to provide the **single best answer**.
This keeps things simple and clear - the answer that was most helpful to the question asker is marked with a tick at the top of the list.
Any other answers come directly below, in order of 'helpfulness' with votes decided by the OP and other members of the community.
There is no confusion about multiple answers, there is only ever one (provided that the OP has marked it as such).

The simple rules for the question asker are:

1. Mark the post that best answers your question as 'the answer'.
2. Upvote any other answers that have helped you.