# How to mark all responses as correct which collectively answer a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

From this post [How can I mark two responses as answers?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243/how-can-i-mark-two-responses-as-answers), I understand that to keep things clear only one answer can be marked as accepted.

However,there may be kind of questions (like [List of SharePoint development tools](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81/list-of-sharepoint-2007-wss-3-0-development-tools/)  and [Design Principles and Patterns in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22620/design-principles-and-patterns-in-sharepoint)) for which a real answer is combination of many answers.

Is there a way to mark the answers which contribute to the real answer as a whole?
Also, does it make sense to start bounty for such questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, only one answer can be marked as accepted. For the type of general question you describe, the StackExchange way of dealing with these is to make them a [Community Wiki](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki).

Comment: +1. In general, we try to avoid questions that can't be answered definitively. However, we have been relatively lenient so far. :)

Comment: Thanks @SPDoctor and @KitMenke!